# How to get background and foreground pixels of view in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view, android-graphics

> I have two questions one related to background and other for
>   foreground

**1:** I am trying of get background covered pixels of view for example as shown in picture 
             with 
    respect of view2 I want to get its background covered pixels that pixels has some part from 
    view 1 and view 3

**2** You can imagine same example for view3 I want to get its foreground covered pixels(part of view2) and background pixels (part of view1)

I know some previous knowledge such as 
This can get exact location of view where it lays

```
val loc = IntArray(2)
view2.getLocationOnScreen(array)
```

[image: problem example image]